# Why does the Google Translate widget look different from what it should be?

Tags: widget, translation, google-translate

I'm trying to put the Google Translate widget on my page, but it doesn't look like it used to. Is this a change on Google's end? Or is there a setting?

Here is the page where I'm getting the code:
http://translate.google.com/manager/website/settings

This is how it used to look:

[image]

**But this is what I'm getting** when I use Google's code to add the widget to my page: [image]

Strangely, on their site, the picture of the plugin that you are getting looks like the first photo above (the one I want), but I end up with the 2nd when I'm using their live code. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the first picture is identical to 'Dropdown only' under 'Display mode' -> 'Inline', while the second picture to the same to 'Vertical'.

And I check the differences between these two in terms of snippet, and I suggest you can put ", layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE" between '({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element')'.

In other words, try the following:

function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
}